# Sum function for a matrix

Tags: c

I have a problem where I need to compute the sum of the even numbers from the first diagonal of a square matrix, but the sum needs to be a sepparate function. This is what I've got so far but it won't compile :(

CODE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void suma(int m[5][5])
{
    int i,j,s=0,m[5][5];
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        for(j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            if(i==j&&m[i][j]%2==0)
            {
                s = s + m[i][j];
            }
        }
    printf("\n\nSuna numerelor pare de pe prima diagonala este:\t");
    printf("%d",s);
}

int main()
{
    int i,j,s=0,m[5][5];
    printf("Introduceti matricea \n");
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        for(j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&m[i][j]);
        }
    printf("\nMatricea dvs este:\n");
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        printf("\n");
        for(j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            printf("\t%d",m[i][j]);
        }
    }

    suma(m[i][j]);

}
```

Comment: `int i,j,s=0,m[5][5];` you are re-declaring `m`. One as function parameter and another within the function.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: @kiranBiradar now it compiles but the sum is a ridiculously huge number

Comment: You call to `suma` is wrong, you don't pass `m`, but pass `m[i][j]` (which is a single `int` value, and when both `i` and `j` are *out of bounds!*) Your compiler should have issued warning about it.

Comment: Do you need a double loop for a diagonal? `for(i=0;i<5;i++) if(m[i][i]%2==0)  s=s+m[i][i];` seems enough.

Comment: `suma(m[i][j]);` is wrong too, compile with warnings. The compiler will most likely only produce a warning, but it's actually an error.

Answer (score 0):

When you compile the code with [GCC compiler](https://godbolt.org/z/ECuoKX) the following options `-Wall -pedantic-errors` produces the following warnings:

```
<source>: In function 'void suma(int (*)[5])':
<source>:6:23: error: declaration of 'int m [5][5]' shadows a parameter
     int i,j,s=0,m[5][5];
                       ^
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:38:16: error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int (*)[5]' [-fpermissive]
     suma(m[i][j]);
          ~~~~~~^
<source>:4:15: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'void suma(int (*)[5])'
 void suma(int m[5][5])
           ~~~~^~~~~~~
<source>:21:13: warning: unused variable 's' [-Wunused-variable]
     int i,j,s=0,m[5][5];
         ^
```

After eliminating these errors/warnings, your code will now be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void suma(int m[5][5])
{
    int i, s = 0;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        if(m[i][i]%2==0)
            s = s + m[i][i];
    printf("\n\nSuna numerelor pare de pe prima diagonala este:\t");
    printf("%d",s);
}

int main()
{
    int i,j,m[5][5];
    printf("Introduceti matricea \n");
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        for(j=0;j<5;j++)
            scanf("%d",&m[i][j]);

    printf("\nMatricea dvs este:\n");
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        printf("\n");
        for(j=0;j<5;j++)
            printf("\t%d",m[i][j]);
    }

    suma(m);
}
```